# How can i detect the number of polygon is drawed in a edit session in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am working with qgis 1.8 and i want to know how many polygon drawed in one edit sessions
 is there any signal emitted with qgis ???

Answer (score 1):

The signal [QgsVectorLayer.featureAdded( QgsFeatureId fid )](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac914dd316a4bb50eb432515950583806) is emitted whenever a new feature is added to the layer.

If you have to group the count by edit sessions you can also connect to the signals [editingStarted](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a476eaf6ec8f2a45e285e963bcacedcc2) and [editingStopped](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1bbb8282e76b83dabf6ad5dd7fbe62b7).

Use like:

```
layer.featureAdded.connect(yourhandlermethod)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer so in python i have:
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
i can use it like this :
layer.featureAdded( QgsFeatureId fid ) ?

Comment: i obtaint this error :
     native Qt signal is not callable

Comment: See edited answer.